# Different order of argument for LIKE changes result

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have very strange situation in MySQL (MariaDB). I have a query with:

- two `keywords`
- one `location`
- one `salary`
- one `limit`

If `keywords` args are put in different order I get different results:

Query #1:

```
bindings: [ '%Javascript%', '%Vue.js%', 'Krakow', '3000', 15 ],
sql:
   'select `jobs`.*,`companies`.`name`as `company_name`, 
            `companies`.`logo` as `company_logo`, `projects`.`staff`, 
            `projects`.`breakdown`, `projects`.`methodology`, 
            `projects`.`stack`, `projects`.`perks` 
    from `jobs` 
        inner join `companies` on `jobs`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
        inner join `projects` on `jobs`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` 
    where `keywords` like ? 
       or `keywords` like ? 
       and `location` = ? 
       and `salary_min` >= ? 
    order by `jobs`.`salary_min` desc 
    limit ?' }
count:  45
```

Query #2:

```
bindings: [ '%Vue.js%', '%Javascript%', 'Krakow', '3000', 15 ],
sql:
   'select `jobs`.*, `companies`.`name`as `company_name`, 
            `companies`.`logo` as `company_logo`, `projects`.`staff`, 
            `projects`.`breakdown`, `projects`.`methodology`, 
            `projects`.`stack`, `projects`.`perks` 
    from `jobs` 
        inner join `companies` on `jobs`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
        inner join `projects` on `jobs`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` 
    where `keywords` like ? 
       or `keywords` like ? 
      and `location` = ? 
      and `salary_min` >= ? 
    order by `jobs`.`salary_min` desc 
    limit ?' }
count:  6
```

Problems:
- why it's not returning jobs only from selected `location`?
- why is there count difference because of `keywords` order?

Would love to understand that - can't wrap my head around it. I'm using Knex for performing these queries.

Comment: If you are using `OR` in the WHERE clause it is always best to use Parenthesis as well

Comment: Short answer: put parentheses around your `OR`.

Comment: `where ( \`keywords\` like ? OR \`keywords\` like ? ) AND ......`

Comment: Your first query: ``keywords` like ? 
       or (`keywords` like ? 
       and `location` = ? 
       and `salary_min` >= ?)`.  Your second query: ``keywords` like ? 
       or (`keywords` like ? 
       and `location` = ? 
       and `salary_min` >= ?)`.  Of course it will give you different result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND` has a higher precedence than `OR`.  Put bracket around your `OR` statement.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
select `jobs`.*, `companies`.`name`as `company_name`, 
        `companies`.`logo` as `company_logo`, `projects`.`staff`, 
        `projects`.`breakdown`, `projects`.`methodology`, 
        `projects`.`stack`, `projects`.`perks` 
from `jobs` 
    inner join `companies` on `jobs`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` 
    inner join `projects` on `jobs`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` 
where (`keywords` like ? 
   or `keywords` like ?) 
  and `location` = ? 
  and `salary_min` >= ? 
order by `jobs`.`salary_min` desc 
limit ?
```